# inconsistent behaviour of extended glob patterns in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

The following Bash (v 5.1.4) script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $BASHOPTS
shopt extglob
x="123"
if [[ "$x" == +([[:digit:]]) ]]; then 
    echo "[[ Ok!" 
fi
case $x in
    +([[:digit:]])) echo "case Ok" ;;
    *) echo case "KO" ;;
esac
```

outputs

```
checkwinsize:cmdhist:complete_fullquote:extquote:force_fignore:globasciiranges:hostcomplete:interactive_comments:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath
extglob         off
[[ Ok!
./extglob_test.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./extglob_test.sh: line 10: `    +([[:digit:]])) echo "case Ok" ;;'
```

which raises several questions to me:

1. `shopt extglob` says it's off, so case option in line 9 logically fails. But why code in line 5 succeeds then?
2. The env variable BASHOPTS contains the inherited shopt options, and the BASH manual states that:

   ```
   BASHOPTS
     A  colon-separated  list of enabled shell options.  Each word in the list is a valid argument for the -s option to the shopt
     builtin command (see SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).  The options appearing in BASHOPTS are those reported as  on  by  shopt.
     If this variable is in the environment when bash starts up, each shell option in the list will be enabled before reading any
     startup files.  This variable is read-only.
   ```

   So I'd expect to see `extglob` enabled in the script. And indeed, issuing an `echo $BASHOPTS` command at the shell prompt outputs:

   ```
   checkwinsize:cmdhist:complete_fullquote:expand_aliases:extglob:extquote:force_fignore:globasciiranges:histappend:interactive_comments:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath
   ```

   However, we can see there are some differences, and notably the option `extglob` which is present here, but missing in the output from the script.

   Of course, if I enable `extglob` option with `shopt -s extglob` in line 3 of the script, I get:

   ```
   checkwinsize:cmdhist:complete_fullquote:extquote:force_fignore:globasciiranges:hostcomplete:interactive_comments:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath
   [[ Ok!
   case Ok
   ```
3. However, the linter (I use Ale in Vim) still signals a syntax error in line 9

Any ideas?

Comment: Inside the `[[ ]]` extglob is enabled by default, well at least according to my man pages, so it does not need the `shopt` to enable it. To jump directly at the relevant section of the man page try:  `PAGER="less +/^[[:space:]]*'\[\['" man bash` , In the `case` statement the `(` and ` )`   is special to the shell so that is an expected error imo. Also I don't think the case statement can handle that pattern for `extglob`.

Comment: "BASHOPTS contains the inherited shopt options [...] So I'd expect to see extglob enabled in the script." -- err, why? If BASHOPTS doesn't contain it at the start of the script, then the script didn't get it from the calling context, right? Also, BASHOPTS doesn't appear to be exported by default, so unless you explicitly did that, it wouldn't get inherited from the parent shell.

Comment: 3. does the linter deal with extglob patterns in other contexts? Like `ls -l +([[:digit:]])`. Like you said, that `case` does work ok, and also e.g. shellcheck.net parses it correctly.

Comment: One should always read carefully the doc !
Thanks all

Comment: The error in your linter probably appears because the `case` condition is normally incorrect (`extglob` is off by default). If you put it into a function in your Bash script, it will throw a syntax error, unless you turn on extglob _before_ parsing the function. Thus, take care with functions! Compare a [script with error](https://pastebin.com/y1JPLRSV) to a [script that succeeds](https://pastebin.com/JQX5rTBH). It's not intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 questions.

1. As comments have said, inside `[[` extglob is enabled by default.
2. You don't have an environment variable BASHOPTS. You can see this by running `export | grep BASHOPTS` and not seeing anything. As you quote "**If** this variable is in the environment when bash starts up..." you need to run `export BASHOPTS` in your interactive shell.
3. Get a better linter!.

Comment: or `declare -p BASHOPTS` and look for the missing `-x`.